# Android check for Google Play Services APK when using GameHelper

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play-services

Do I have to check if Google Play Services APK is available if I want to use AdMob and GameHelper (from BaseGameUtils apk). Do I have to add a uses-library tag to my manifest?

thx & regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't HAVE to check for the presence of Google Play Services, but Google recommend that you do:

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure

If you do not check, and Google Play Services is not installed, Android will prompt the user to install Google Play Services.

You do not need a "uses-library" tags in your manifest. Your project is able to access the BaseGameUtils (including GameHelper) because you set it up as a library project and reference it in your project. 
See https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart for a detailed explanation of the steps required.